# Java multi threading when multiple threads updating same variable

Tags: java, multithreading

This is the program

```
public class Thread2 implements Runnable {

    private static int runTill = 10000;
    private static int count = 0;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i=0;i<runTill;i++) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String s[]) {
        int iteration = 10;
        for(int i = 0; i < iteration ;i++) {
            Thread t = new Thread(new Thread2());
            t.start();
        }
        
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        System.out.println("Expected : "+(iteration * runTill));
        System.out.println("Actual : "+count);
    }

}
```

At the end I want count to be equal to (Expected : 100000). How can I achieve this?

Comment: Probably the smartest way is to use `AtomicInteger.getAndIncrement()`.  https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#getAndIncrement()  Is there a reason why you are not using the `java.util.concurrent` package API?

Comment: Besides AtomicInteger, you can also consider synchronization and locks. especially if you want to manage more than just an integer (see https://winterbe.com/posts/2015/04/30/java8-concurrency-tutorial-synchronized-locks-examples/)

Comment: Also, don't simply sleep to wait for the thread to complete: put the threads into a list, and use `Thread.join()` to wait for their completion.

Comment: Yes, I want to reinforce "don't use sleep()".  Calling sleep like this to wait for threads is a terrible idea.  Please call `Thread.join()` on each thread, or use something like a `CountDownLatch`

Comment: @Abra No, I think the OP is asking how to update a shared variable.  His final result (100,000) is too large to be one single thread updating a instance variable 10,000 times.

Answer (score 2):

A call to `count++` is not atomic: it first has to load `count`, increment it and then store the new value in the variable. Without synchronization in place, threads will interleave during execution of this operation.

A simple way to get what you want is to use an [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html):

```
private static AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger();

@Override
public void run() {
    for(int i=0;i<runTill;i++) {
        count.incrementAndGet();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use "compare and set" instead of "increment and get"

```
private static AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger();

@Override
public void run() {
    for(int i=0;i<runTill;i++) {

        //note: another thread might reach this point at the same time when i is 9,999
        // (especially if you have other codes running prior to the increment within the for loop)
        // then count will be added 2x if you use incrementAndGet
        boolean isSuccessful = count.compareAndSet(i, i+1);

        if(!isSuccessful) 
            System.out.println("number is not increased (another thread already updated i)");
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think compare and set is a good match to the OP's (implied) use case.  Also this is not a great way to handle an unsuccessful update.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments suggest, besides the need for synchronizing access (to `count`, became an `AtomicInteger` here), threads should be waited to complete using `Thread.join()`, instead of "guessing" their runtime:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Thread2 implements Runnable {

    private static int runTill = 10000;
    private static AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger();

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < runTill; i++) {
            count.incrementAndGet();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String s[]) {
        int iteration = 10;
        List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
        for (int i = 0; i < iteration; i++) {
            Thread t = new Thread(new Thread2());
            threads.add(t);
            t.start();
        }

        try {
            for (Thread t : threads)
                t.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Expected : " + (iteration * runTill));
        System.out.println("Actual : " + count);
    }
}
```